# What is the benefit of using RxJava, RxKotlin, or Even Kotlin coroutines instead of Interfaces for On Click listener?

Tags: android, android-studio, rx-java, kotlin-coroutines, rx-kotlin

My Question is so clear, I wanna know what is the reason that you prefer using third-party libraries like RxJava or RxKotlin, or using coroutines for setting item click listener for Recyclerview items click, dialogs button or anything else, instead of using Interfaces, is there any performance reason?
what is the difference between these tools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Onclicklistener used to handle clicks on activity
and
Rxjava used to manage threads